# Designing Spring-Security UserDetails class with embedded classes for UserCredentials and UserPermissions

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Im trying to design a simple IAM-alike-tool to manage users in a university project.

When designing the whole app, we decided that it makes sense to move user credentials and user permissions to separate classes. Mostly because of the fact, that there are generally two use cases for user to exist - in terms of authentication and authorization, and in terms of e.g. managing his profile from "manager's" perspective.

The classes have been implemented as follows (Hibernate mappings and others omitted for brevity):

```
public abstract class User {
    // id + personal data
    private AccountCredentials credentials;
    private AccountPermissions permissions;
}

public class AccountPermissions {
    // Sets of Fine-grained and Coarse-grained authorities, that are merged into single 
    // set for the purpose of UserDetails.getAuthorities() method
}

public class AccountCredentials {
    // id, username, encrypted pwd, salt, email
}
```

Since I want to use the User class in Spring Security Filter Chain and JWT generation, I need to define methods such as

```
Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
Boolean existsByUsername(String username);
Boolean existsByEmail(String email);
```

Is there a convenient way of defining such methods that work upon classes embedded within entities ("find-by-username-in-user-credentials")- in terms of Spring Data JPA generating queries for those methods?

Comment: `it is not possbile to make Spring Data JPA generate those for me` what are you talking about, if you have proper relationship annotations on your entities jpa can generate the table structore for you? what properties are you referring to? it is best practice to keep your entity classes seperate from your DTO (data transfer objects) since otherwise you are tightly coupling your database structure to your api. Which is bad

Comment: @Toerktumlare To be honest, i have no clue about things you point out here.
The sentence "it is not possbile to make Spring Data JPA generate those for me" clearly reffers to generation of methods implementation, based on properties within embedded classes of my entity. Moreover, you have missed an important fact - I added AFAIK on the beginning of that sentence, as I was not sure if this was possisble with Spring Data JPA.

Generating propper table structure or handling data in terms of DTOs and Entities is not a matter of this post - I suggest reading those more carefully next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spring's nested queries, which rely solely on method names and you don't need to write any boilerplate code or queries.

This should look more or less like (note the underscore):

```java
Optional<User> findByCredentials_Username(String username);
```

More details and use-cases can be found [here](https://stacktraceguru.com/springboot/nested-object-query).

Regarding the naming convention, you could try working around it by providing default methods, which calls the less visually pleasant query-methods and possibly marking those as private, but without checking I'm not 100% sure it will work with Spring's Proxy classes. And this is some boilerplate code you would need to provide, so I guess it's better to just stick with default conventions.

```java
default Optional<User> findByUsername(String username) {
    return findByCredentials_Username(username);
}
```